# element null when trying to get rendered height of element in pure JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why doesn't [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ghhxddnj/17/) code work? I am trying to (without JQuery) get the rendered height of an html element. This code below:

html:

```
<body id="logo">
</body>
```

css:

```
body { 
    background-image: url('https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_284x96dp.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100vw auto;
    background-position: -80px 50%; 
}
```

JS:

```
var element = document.getElementById(logo).offsetHeight;
console.log(element);
```

But this code gives this error:

> VM227:51 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of null

What have I doen wrong?

Comment: you need `document.getElementById("logo")`, with " "

Comment: @itsgoingdown Ohhh, stupid me! Thanks! Is this the correct approach to do what I am trying to achieve? If you see my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ghhxddnj/18/) then it reports `height: 0` ?

Comment: There is no content in the element so the height is zero

Answer (score 0):

your code should be more like this:

```
document.getElementById('logo')
```

otherwise you are trying to get the element with the id into the var logo.

regards

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("logo").offsetHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, logo is currently a variable. You need to surround with quotes, so:

```
document.getElementById("logo")
```

Note, offsetHeight also gives you the height of any paddings and borders.